# AVCamDemo - completion handler for captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection doesn't get called

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, 3g, avcam

I've modified the `AVCamDemo` from `WWDC 2010` to use `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` instead of `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`.  This **works fine with iPhone 3GS** (iOS 4.3.5), but when using an iPhone 3G (iOS 4.2.1), the completion handler for `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` **never gets called**, and the preview **layer freezes** on the last frame.

Has anyone else seen this behavior or know how to explain it?

Comment: I experience this issue as well, I tested all possible solutions/fixes I came up with, but it doesn't get fixed and I assume it may relate to the hardware problem. Anyone found an answer or experience it?